# Can't access local devices connected to Fritz!Box

Tags: router, port-forwarding, fritzbox

I'm using a FRITZ!Box 7530 router, and I can't access the FTP server created on one of the connected devices from other connected devices. Keep in mind that the `Active wireless devices may communicate with each other` option is already checked, and I have tried resetting the router to its factory settings. With the same setup, if I connect both devices to any other router, the FTP connection works perfectly.

Comment: can the devices ping the FTP server? Depending on the OS and FTP software, you might need to adjust the IP, firewall rules, or FTP listener binding when you connect to the new router

Comment: Hey @Cpt.Whale, thank you for your message. FTP is just an example. The devices can not ping each other in any way. If it helps both devices are MacBook. And please keep in mind that if I connect both devices to any other router they can communicate with each other.

Comment: Are both devices connected to the wireless network? I've found many people having similar issues where the LAN ports act like they're isolated from the wifi and/or each other (https://superuser.com/q/1274884/673426 for example), but no real solutions. Make sure that you don't have guest network enabled on individual ports?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, Guest network is turned off. And yes both devices are connected to the wireless network.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale is there any other information that I should provide so that this issue can be further investigated?